# How to add level to appender in manual code configuration in log4j2?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

From [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/faq.html#config_sep_appender_level)

> You don’t need to declare separate loggers to achieve this. You can
>   set the logging level on the AppenderRef element.

And xml example (part):

```
<Root level="trace">
  <AppenderRef ref="file" level="DEBUG"/>
  <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" level="INFO"/>
</Root>
```

But I can't find a way to do it when I create configuration myself. For example I have consoleAppenderBuilder and rootLoggerBuilder:

```
AppenderComponentBuilder consoleAppenderBuilder = builder
    .newAppender("Stdout", "CONSOLE")
    .addAttribute("target", ConsoleAppender.Target.SYSTEM_OUT);

RootLoggerComponentBuilder rootLoggerBuilder = builder
    .newRootLogger(Level.ERROR)
    .add(builder.newAppenderRef("Stdout"));
```

How to add console appender to root logger and define log level for appender. I am asking this because I want to add multiple appenders to root logger.

Comment: I understand that you wanted to know how to configure the appender level programmatically but it feels like this could be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) in that you may not really need to do programmatic configuration to achieve the results you want. Could you please explain why you want to configure log4j2 in this way? If you can avoid programmatic configuration then you can prevent your code from depending on the log4j2 implementation and instead rely on the public interface, which saves you some trouble in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is one way of setting log level for each `Appender` in `RootLogger` -

```
AppenderComponentBuilder consoleAppenderBuilder = builder
    .newAppender("Stdout", "CONSOLE")
    .addAttribute("target", ConsoleAppender.Target.SYSTEM_OUT);

RootLoggerComponentBuilder rootLoggerBuilder = builder
    .newRootLogger(Level.ALL)
    .add(builder.newAppenderRef("Stdout").addAttribute("level", Level.INFO));
```

If you have multiple appenders, below code can work -

```
RootLoggerComponentBuilder rootLoggerBuilder = builder
    .newRootLogger(Level.ALL)
    .add(builder.newAppenderRef("Stdout").addAttribute("level", Level.INFO)).add(builder.newAppenderRef("fileAppender").addAttribute("level", Level.ERROR));
```

The only point to remember is `Appender` log level can reduce logging Level given in `logger` but can not increase logging level.

Suppose in above example, level in `RootLogger` initialization is `Level.ALL` and for `Stdout` appender, it is `Level.INFO`. So, it will print logs of `INFO` level and above (`WARN`, `ERROR`). However, the reverse will not work i.e. if `RootLogger` has `Level.INFO` and `Stdout` appender has `Level.All`, in that case also, it will print logs of `INFO` level and above.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative approach you could add a [ThresholdFilter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/filters.html#ThresholdFilter) using the following [example from the manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/customconfig.html#Example) to guide you (it uses MarkerFilter but should be similar process).